# XCode 6 - SWIFT - Access Multiple Items In Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this:

```
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

println("You should know your \(alphabet)'s")
```

How do I access `a, b, c`?

I've tried `\(alphabet[0...3])'s` and `\(alphabet['0', '1', '2'])'s`  and `\(alphabet[0,1,2)'s` to no avail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with `alphabet[0..2]`, but what you were missing is the `join` function which concatenates strings using a separator:

```
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
let section = alphabet[0...2]
let s = join(", ", section) // Separator goes in the ""
println(s) // a, b, c
```

Also, there is no reason to use `var` for the alphabet so use `let`

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe the `join` function isn't mentioned in the array tuts/docs that I've come across, and I've looked at a number of them. I really appreciate it.